# LLVM Swift Compilation remove unused parameters

Tags: swift, compilation, llvm

Is it possible for LLVM to remove unused parameters in precompilation?
For example:

```swift
// Non compiled code
func doSomething(a: Int, b: Int) { // "b" is unused
  compute(a)
}
```

Compile to something equal to this code:

```swift
// Expected compiled code
func doSomething(a: Int) {
  compute(a)
}
```

Comment: It is change of interface contract. How would use it and why would you need it?